# How to handle multiple errors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I run something like

```
BACKUP LOG [somedb] 
TO DISK = N'i:\log.bak';
```

It throws 2 errors messages:

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot open backup device 'i:\log.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find    the path specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally.
```

When I try to handle the error with a TRY CATCH the error returned is always 3013. This is a problem for me because I want to know if the backup failed due to lack of space, or if the drive isn't present, etc.

Using @@ERROR returns the same error number.

Is there any way to handle multiple error messages like these?

Answer (score 4):

You need to inspect the `Errors` collection inside the `SqlException`:

```
catch(SqlException sqlEx)
{
    foreach(SqlError error in sqlEx.Errors)
    {
       int code = error.Number;
       string msg = error.Message;
    }
 }
```

You should get all error with all relevant details in the `SqlException.Errors`

Comment: @MikeDaSpike: no, not to my knowledge - not even with the `TRY..CATCH` mechanism :-(

Comment: @Mike - Not easily. `DBCC OUTPUTBUFFER(@@spid).` might be able to do it but you'll need to [figure out how to parse the output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697492/capturing-multiple-error-messages-from-a-single-statement/5773071#5773071)

Comment: Damn, I guess it's an excuse to go into C#. Thanks.