# Catching selective exceptions in a stream

Tags: sql-server, try-catch

certain operations upon failure generate multiple exceptions. Consider the following:

```
use tempdb
go
create table x (i int, s char(32))
go
create table y (a int, xi int)
go
alter table y add constraint y_xi foreign key (xi) references x(i)
go
```

which generates:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 There are no primary or candidate
>   keys in the referenced table 'x' that match the referencing column
>   list in the foreign key 'y_xi'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

were one to wrap a try/catch around this operation, one could pick up only the *last* of the exceptions, whereas the first is actually of greater interest:

```
begin try
    alter table y add constraint y_xi foreign key (xi) references x(i)
end try
begin catch
    print error_number()
end catch
```

which generates 1750 - this tells me that the constraint could not be created but not why.  1776 would be much more useful but I can't figure out how to pick it up.

ideas anyone?

TIA - e!

Comment: i believe this question is a duplicate of this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697492/capturing-multiple-error-messages-from-a-single-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the answer is it cannot be done.  apparently SQL Server 2012 addresses the issue in some manner as per this article:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3476a931-3db7-4017-9fbe-e082f2de2cb0/sql-server-trycatch-inner-exception-message-conundrum?forum=transactsql

thanks @user3973227 for pointing this out!