# How to get all state Error in try catch block

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I get all state error in SQL Server 2008/2012?

I am using `Try catch` block in my stored procedure for error message and return error message if any error occur.

I am trying to alter one table column which is associated with other object so when I am change that column datatype SQL Server return an error

> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Abc_col1 failed because one or more objects access this column.

When I am executing only alter script in Sql it will give me 2 error messages as below

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'fn_Abc_state' is dependent on column 'Abc_col1 '.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Abc_col1 failed because one or more objects access this column.

when compare both message only **state** is different

my question is **How we can get all the Error message when it's occur while executing my Sp along with state**  as below

```
State 1 = The object 'fn_ABC_state' is dependent on column 'Abc_col1 '. 
State 9 = ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Abc_col1 failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM sys.[messages]` gives you all messages defined in your SQL Server system. Which **state** they'll be associated with depends on where and when the error occurs and cannot be stored ahead of time in this system catalog view

Comment: Hello marc_s, but how can i get it from sp? all the time i am get only one error that was **ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Abc_col1 failed because one or more objects access this column.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing multiple error messages from a single statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697492/capturing-multiple-error-messages-from-a-single-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You can see all level of error messages like:

```
BEGIN TRY  
    --divide-by-zero error.  
    SELECT 1/0;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
           ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
           ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
           ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
           ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
           ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
END CATCH;  
GO
```

You can also use "THROW" keyword to return all errors like:

```
BEGIN CATCH; 
   THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Please also note that the query below returns you all the messages for your DB

```
SELECT * FROM sys.[messages]
```

Reference1: http://www.sqlusa.com/articles2008/trycatch/
Reference2: https://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.ca/2016/09/Enhanced-TSQL-Error-Handling-With-Extended-Events.html