# Store 'throw' output into a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, bulkinsert

In my sql Server (2012) I am having a `bulk insert` (inside a stored proccedure) command which upon an error may raise up to three errors.

For example

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 8, column 1 (id).
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The  provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I am wrapping this `bulk insert` into a `try / catch` block in order to catch the error, store it and propably re-raise it.

I am uring `error_message()` to get the error and `raiseerror` to re-raise it. The known problem in this case is that `error_message()` return only the last error thrown, which my case is the less informative.

Using `throw` ([THROW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx)) I can re-raise all the `bulk insert` errors in my catch block. But this just prints them in the screen.

What I am trying know to do (and I falling) is to store this information from `throw` in a variable in order to used it afterwards e.g. store it somewhere.

I tried to having nested `try / catch`, but still I cannot get the throw information into a variable. I already read the sugestions from [Capturing multiple error messages from a single statement inside TRY CATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697492/capturing-multiple-error-messages-from-a-single-statement-inside-try-catch), but still I can not achieve  what I am trying to.

Comment: It's up to you how to handle thrown errors. In the calling procedure or application you can store the error message in a variable, or print it on the Screen whatever you want.

Comment: @CPMunich I want to handle the error on the SQL Server. I can not achieve to store all the errors thrown by throw in one variable (as string), that is my problem. If I use `error_message()` I can get only the last error, but I want all of them (3 in my case).

Answer (score 1):

I have found this code to be extremely useful for collecting all errors and outputting to a table:

```
DECLARE @Spid varchar(6);
DECLARE @Sql varchar(max);
SELECT @Spid = @@spid
SET @sql = 'CREATE EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(' + @spid + ')]
ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported
(
ACTION(
    sqlserver.session_id,
    sqlserver.sql_text
)
WHERE [package0].[not_equal_unicode_string]([message],N'''''''''''') 
AND [severity]>(10) 
AND [sqlserver].[session_id]=(' + @spid + ')
) 
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
WITH (
  --ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS
  --NO_EVENT_LOSS
  EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
  MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,
  MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=1 SECONDS,
  MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,
  MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,
  TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,
  STARTUP_STATE=OFF
);

ALTER EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(' + @spid + ')] ON SERVER         
STATE=START;';
EXEC(@Sql);

BEGIN TRY
  BACKUP LOG [WrongDBName]
  TO DISK = 'D:\some_destination\that\does\not\exist\NeverGonnaHappen.trn'
  WITH
    NAME = 'Transaction Backup',
    NO_COMPRESSION,
    STATS = 10;    

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  DECLARE @XEData XML
  DECLARE @XEName varchar(100) = 'Error Handling Session(' + @spid + ')' 

  SELECT @XEData = CAST(xet.target_data AS XML)
  FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xet
  JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xe ON (xe.address = xet.event_session_address)
  WHERE xe.name = @XEName;

  /*
  Check value of "totalEventsProcessed" to ensure events have been 
  dispatched to event session target (ring_buffer).
  If no events have been processed, delay for a period of MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY +1 (in seconds).
  */
  IF @XEData.value('(/RingBufferTarget/@totalEventsProcessed)[1]', 'INT') = 0
  BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';

    SELECT @XEData = CAST(xet.target_data AS XML)
    FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xet
    JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xe
        ON (xe.address = xet.event_session_address)
    WHERE xe.name = @XEName;
  END

  --Comment/uncomment as desired to show the formatted XML session data.
  SELECT @XEData;

  --Shred the XML. Do whatever you want with this data: 
  -- log it to a table, create and send an email alert, etc.
  SELECT 
    x.c.value(N'(@name)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS EventName,
    x.c.value(N'(@timestamp)[1]', N'datetime') AS EventTime,
    x.c.value(N'(data[@name="error_number"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS ErrorNumber,
    x.c.value(N'(data[@name="severity"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Severity,
    x.c.value(N'(data[@name="state"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [State],
    x.c.value(N'(data[@name="user_defined"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS UserDefined,
    x.c.value(N'(data[@name="category"]/text)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Category,
    x.c.value(N'(data[@name="destination"]/text)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Destination,
    x.c.value(N'(data[@name="is_intercepted"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS IsIntercepted,
    x.c.value(N'(data[@name="message"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Message],
    x.c.value(N'(action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS SqlText,
    x.c.value(N'(action[@name="session_id"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS SessionId
FROM @XEData.nodes('//RingBufferTarget/event') AS x(c)
--Uncomment WHERE to show ONLY those errors that would not be normally logged
--WHERE x.c.value(N'(data[@name="destination"]/text)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') = 'USER'

END CATCH;

SET @Sql = 'ALTER EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(' + @Spid + ')] ON SERVER STATE=STOP; DROP EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(' + @Spid + ')] ON SERVER;';
EXEC(@sql);
GO
```

Comment: Adding some explanation (or comments in the code) would make it much easier for others to understand your solution.

Comment: You have no idea how long I've been looking for an answer exactly like this. This is perfect.