# Inner message in SQL Server TRY/CATCH

Tags: sql-server, try-catch

I want handle error in my procedure when running

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDb] TO DISK = 'c:\Test.bak' WITH COMPRESSION;
```

command.

If I run this command without `TRY/CATCH`, I get two errors :

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
> Cannot open backup device 'c:\Test.bak'. Operating system error 5 (Access is denied.).
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

but when I use `TRY/CATCH` in the statement shown here, I get only part two of this error:

```
BEGIN CATCH
        select ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

returned error is only :

> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

How to I can get two part of errors?

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot get all error messages with T-SQL TRY/CATCH. You'll need to forgo T-SQL TRY/CATCH and get the errors in the client application, like SSMS or SQLCMD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing multiple error messages from a single statement inside TRY CATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697492/capturing-multiple-error-messages-from-a-single-statement-inside-try-catch)

Comment: @GSerg really I want log error messages in my log table when I got error.
with THROW command I cant achieve this goal.

Comment: @M.R.Sadeghi, to log all the error messages to a table you'll need to do that in the client application. Note that [Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/) does exactly that for backups and index maintenance so consider using that instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @M.R.Sadeghi Many of the errors render your transaction uncommittable. If you write to your log table, that will be rolled back too. So do it from the client app.

Comment: For additional reference, Erland discusses this exact situation in the [error handling section](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part3.html#backuppresumptions) of his blog.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly I misunderstood the question so  scratch this.

```
SELECT   
     ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
    ,ERROR_LINE () AS ErrorLine  
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
```

Comment: I have removed the perhaps not relevant example. Thanks

Comment: None of these functions allow to retrieve the error message of the previous error in the error chain.