# How can I output the print message from a SQL Server?(DB-Link Error Message)

Tags: sql-server, oracle

As below the code or screenshot, now I have a Link-Server to Oracle DB, and try to execute the error.

But the error message not result Oracle original error code, this is translated by MS SQL.

I need take Oracle original error code(Ex: ORA-01400), it's shown on the "Message Tab".

How can I extract it?

Thanks!

[Demo Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tocq6.png)

```
begin try
    EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC EIP..SP_F_TEST_0602 ''A'' ';
end try
begin catch
  print 'A'
  SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_MESSAGE()
end catch
```

[Message Tab:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tOcx.png)

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "TPE15_WHPR"
> returned message "ORA-01400".

Comment: T-SQL `ERROR_*` functions ` only return one error where multiple occurred here. [Possible dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697492/capturing-multiple-error-messages-from-a-single-statement-inside-try-catch).

Comment: "ORA-01400: cannot insert null into (string) is a specific error to the null value in Oracle."

Comment: Yes I know, I need catch this information to output parameter.

Comment: Sorry, It’s my expression not good.
I want to receive the error code (Ex:ORA-xxx) return from Oracle and save to MS SQL. 
The demo code just an example of try error.