# Trap full message from ERROR_MESSAGE()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, try-catch

I've got an SSIS package that handles DB restores across various environments. The package runs, crafts a restore command from a backup file (RESTORE FILELIST ONLY), stores an SQL command to run on the target server and executes it.

It's solid, but once in a while we run into errors, such as insufficient disk space, or backup sets newer than target server version.
These errors are propagating correctly when executed manually in SSMS outside a TRY/CATCH block. However, when I handle the code in a TRY/CATCH block, the ERROR_MESSAGE() function only returns **RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.** Not very useful.

I know I should provide a minimal reproducible example, but for this exact use case, I can't find a way. Please review the following code block as an example. It is pretty straightforward.

```
DECLARE @BatchID         INT = 1
        ,@RestoreCommand VARCHAR(MAX);

/* Get restore command from queue */
SELECT  @RestoreCommand = drfpq.RestoreDBCommand
FROM    dbo.QueueTable AS drfpq
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND drfpq.BatchID = @BatchID;

BEGIN TRY
    /* Execute restore command */
    EXEC (@RestoreCommand);

    /* Flag restore successful */
    UPDATE  dbo.QueueTable
    SET     RestoreProcessed = 1
    WHERE   BatchID = @BatchID;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    UPDATE  dbo.QueueTable
    SET     ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            ,RestoreSuccessful = 0
            ,LatestChangeDateTime = SYSDATETIME()
    WHERE   1 = 1
            AND BatchID = @BatchID;
END CATCH;
```

In the table's ErrorMessage column, the only error I see is **RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.**
[image]

However if I execute @RestoreCommand outside the TRY/CATCH block, the full message is returned:

***Msg 3169, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 

The database was backed up on a server running version 14.00.3430. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 13.00.5888. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 
 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.***

From a logging perspective, knowing the canned message is better than nothing, but I am then forced to replay the restore command manually in SSMS to find out what went wrong. I need the complete message, and according to MS documentation, ERROR_MESSAGE() used within a TRY/CATCH block is supposed to be that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-message-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

- ***When called in a CATCH block, ERROR_MESSAGE returns the complete text
  of the error message that caused the CATCH block to run**. The text
  includes the values supplied for any substitutable parameters - for
  example, lengths, object names, or times.*

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to trap all details from ERROR_MESSAGE() in a TRY/CATCH block? I've tried INSERT INTO @Table (Col1) EXEC(@RestoreCommand), but no dice.

Comment: It's actually two separate errors. You can't catch multiple errors from within T-SQL. Perhaps remove the `CATCH` completely, and call the code from Powershell or C#, then you should be able to see all errors together

Comment: Come on Charlie! That's not the answer I want...

Comment: Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697492/capturing-multiple-error-messages-from-a-single-statement-inside-try-catch looks like you can use `DBCC OUTPUTBUFFER`. I must say, I often recommend *against* handling errors *at all* in T-SQL because of this and many other issues. It's so much easier to just do `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and catch all errors on the client