# Unable to get data on rows updated in Azure SQL Audit file sys.fn_get_audit_file

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have enabled auditing on Azure SQL Server and Azure SQL MI and when checking on the data stored in fn_get_audit_file I cannot see the response_rows or affected_rows updated for the update/select/insert/delete queries.
Its always showing 0 .
However if I read the the documenation the response_rows shoudl work for both azure sql db and MI and affected_rows only for azure sql db .

what is going wrong and how can I see the response_rows in these azure managed sql databases.

[image]
[image]

I am expecting these reponse_rows or affected_rows to show the data on number of number affected during database action to show in the database audit.

Comment: Please read this article and try to use the script shared on the article to load the audit log files to a database https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-382-loading-multiple-audit-log-files-using-sys-fn/ba-p/3856361

Comment: This is related to loading the audit , I am able to load the audit file and view the data , the problem is I am not able to see the response_rows or affected_rows which is causing an issue since I am looking to figure out how many rows were affected by the audit action of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE

Answer (score 1):

You first have to find out where the auditing logs are stored. So go to your database and check where they are: in my case they were not on the database but at Server level:

[image]

Now go to the Server and check where they are stored:

[image]

Now we see that they are stored on a specific Storage Account. Now go on that specific Storage Account and find the folder in which the `.xel` files are stored (usually it has the name of the database).

And use this query if you want to import one file:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs/weu-cust-npr-mssql-srvr/mydatabase/SqlDbAuditing_ServerAudit/2023-07-29/00_00_06_604_12.xel', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
GO
```

And if you want to query the whole folder for the logs of the whole day:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs/weu-cust-npr-mssql-srvr/mydatabase/SqlDbAuditing_ServerAudit/2023-07-29/', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
GO
```

Comment: Good step by step! I'd also say that, depending on the traffic you have, the "whole day" path might be too heavy to go through, because it would have to load and parse too many files and rows.. in that case if you need info about some specific queries, you'd better locate the file in which they are and point to them directly. Files are named after the UTC time of the first event contained in the file itself, so you can guess which range of times each one contains.

Comment: what's the difference between the server and the database auditing? Is there something different on the per-database audit which is not present in the per-server audit? My guess is that the per-server has at least the same info as the  per-db, with something more.. but I'm not sure of that..

Comment: There is no difference. Looks at the first picture. You can decide to save the audit log at Server level or at database level. But they are the same, it only changes where you store the files

Comment: As a matter of fact, I realized that in some specific cases there are differences: if you have read scale-out replicas to which you connect (using ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly in the connection string), the queries that you do against that read-only copies are tracked inside a "RO" subfolder, which only appears on the per-database audit, but it's not present in the per-server one.. don't know why...

Comment: Interesting @Luke, never checked this. I will have a look

Comment: as a counter-proof of what I said before, the RO folder is also in the per-server audits.. but it seems to be present only if on that database there are accesses to the read-only replicas. I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-server-level-database-level?view=azuresql in which they explain that "Both audits exist side by side. In other words, the database is audited twice in parallel; once by the server policy and once by the database policy"

Comment: From what I've seen so far, I guess that default policies per-server and per-database are the same, so enabling both at the same time is simply a waste of space. You'd want to do so if you have different audit policies on them, or if you want to send audits somewhere by default at server level, and (also) somewhere else on some specific database..

Comment: At this link there should be more info about audit policies, if someone needs this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below approach to get **response_rows** or **affected_rows** to show the data for number of affected rows during database action.

For example, I have created a table **SALES** and did **INSERT**,**UPDATE**,**DELETE**,**SELECT**.
I have enabled the auditing on **Azure SQL SERVER**

You can use the below query

```
SELECT object_name,statement,client_ip,response_rows,affected_rows
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('https://auditstoragegen2.blob.core.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs/dilipserver/db02/SqlDbAuditing_Audit/2023-08-17/06_01_06_683_0.xel', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
GO
```

The above query reads the **.xel** file from storage account URL using the **sys.fn_get_audit_file** procedure and I in the query have selected **object_name**,**statement**,**client_ip**,**response_rows**,**affected_rows**

**Audit Files in Storage Account:**
[image]
**INSERT:**
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE, SELECT,DELETE:**
[image]
[image]