# Modify statement prior execution

Tags: sql

I use an application connected with an sql database. I found using the profiler that the application runs an update query with a syntax error. I don't have access to the application's source code. The result is that the record is not updated. Is there a way to modify the query every time it is executed with something like trigger? I can't use INSTEAD OF because there ism't any record updated or inserted.

Answer (score 0):

This answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319031/1359088 
suggests a way to log to a text file all the errors. You could write a little utility and schedule it to run every hour or whatever, which could read through this log, find the erroneous sql statements, fix them, then run them itself.